# how to include paho mqtt javascript library to an ionic app

Tags: ionic2, mqtt, paho

I want to connect to an mqtt server using my ionic2 app
so I followed this [link](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-paho-js) and downloaded the paho-javascript library.

The zip file is in my downloads folder, as per the link above we just need to include the  tag with src as "mqttws31.js" is the correct procedure to include an external js library to an ionic2 app??

[image: Below is the ionic2 app folder list]

I included the  script tag  in the index.html

> to which location, i have to copy the mqttws.js

Comment: Update the question to show the actual source of the app where you have included the script tag and have you unpacked the zip file and copied the mqttws31.js file into the ionic project?

Comment: Where you copy the file to depends on what you put in the script tag. Like I said earlier include the actual source for the index.html (only the snippet round the script tag should be enough)